# UITableView only with Images

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm developing an iOS App and I want to make a table view, but only with images like the [6G Nano images app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwpkE.jpg). Does anyone know how to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make custom `UITableViewCell`s by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and/or using Interface Builder/XCode. Here are some good tutorials:
[Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) and [Custom UITableViewCell in IB](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/)